RAID1 not mounting on startup
Hello and thank you in advance for any help you can offer. I'll try and keep this organized as best I can.

My overall goal is to have a new installation of Ubuntu 24.04 with the root on an SSD and the home directory on a RAID1 of two HDD. The Ubuntu installer does not show raid arrays to facilitate this on install so I installed everything to the SSD.

After installation of the OS I created partitions on each of the HDD and made their type "Linux raid" using fdisk. I used mdadm to create the array (/dev/md0) from these two partitions and made a ext4 filesystem on the array. I am able to mount the array without difficulty. I updated the mdadm.conf with the array and verified the UUID is correct being the RAID array.

I went about to move the home directory to the new array by backing up /home to a new directory, copying /home to the array (I have tried both cp -rp, and rsync -a for this) and then deleting /home and creating a new /home. I am able to mount the array to /home after this.

I update the fstab to mount the array to /home (tried both as /dev/md0 and as the UUID) (drive or UUID) /home ext4 default 0 0 (the last tried as both 0 or 2). And update the initramfs.

On reboot the login screen comes up but after putting in the password the screen returns to the login screen and the keyboard and mouse stop working. By entering terminal mode at this point I can see from journalctl that /dev/md0 failed to mount with the error "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error". To investigate this I restored the /home files from my backup and attempted to have the array mount to another location via fstab but on reboot I find the mount failed with the same error as before but if continue with booting I am able to manually mount the array once the system is up.

I have checked the the array and it is always "clean" and there are no failures, errors, bad sectors, etc.


I feel like there is something I am forgetting to update or some helper file I'm not generating.
I am by no means a guru but I am comfortable in terminal.
I have not uploaded any outputs to keep this as clean as possible and if someone sees an easy fix but will post any outputs or additional information as needed.
Of note (not sure if this makes a difference) I noticed the installation didn't make a partition with efi, only bios.

It's a small point, but afaik the fstab mount option should be defaults rather than default

@steeldriver make that an answer so OP can accept it.

Steeldriver, you are a steely-eyed fstab man. It's been so long since I had to mess in these areas I totally overlooked over that I had input "default" instead of "defaults"! Thank you. The system is up and running and I'm sufficiently humbled.
